# Mechanize: Internet banking form fill and submit throws the same error regardless of whether I use the right login details

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to make a script to login to my bank. I successfully made this, but suddenly it stopped working and I CANNOT figure out why. I contacted my bank- they told me that they havn't changed anything their end that would explain why it doesnt work (i.e., prevent bots from logging in). Further, I have a php script that works fine. I don't like php and want it to work in python using mechanize however. This is my code:

```
import mechanize

def scrapeBank(): 

url = 'https://online.lloydsbank.co.uk/personal/logon/login.jsp'
userName = 'XXXX'
firstPassword = 'XXXX'
secondPassword = 'XXXX'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open(url)

f = open("output1.html","w+")
f.write(br.response().read())
f.close()  

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_userID'] = userName
br.form['frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_pwd'] = firstPassword
br.submit()

f = open("output2.html","w+")
f.write(br.response().read())
f.close()  

scrapeBank()
```

Now, what I would expect to see in output2.html (and what I used to see before it stopped working) is the second stage of the login- where you need to enter the second password. Instead, I get the error "Sorry, we've had to log you off...". Now- I get the SAME error if I use an incorrect username and password, or if I don't even complete this fields at all. This is NOT expected behaviour. Expected behaviour, if I use the wrong details, is an error saying as much (this is what happens if I input the wrong details manually in a browser). Expected behaviour if I don't enter any details is that it shouldn't submit the form at all since the username and password are required fields. This implies to me that the br.submit() is doing something weird.

**In summary**
If you visit the url above in your browser and put in a random username or password, you will be told your login is wrong. Yet if you run the above code (you should be able to copy and paste it and run it easily if you have mechanize installed), you will NOT get this- you get 'you have been logged off..' (you can view output2.html to see this) error- or at least this is what I get. So- why is the functionality different between logging in with a browser, and using mechanize?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code a bit such that it can be copy and pasted and run yourself. The question I guess is, if you run it and view output2.html, do you get a 'incorrect username' error- which you should (the same error you'd get if you tried manually in a browser)- or do you get a 'we had to log you off' error?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How would we know? Not everyone's from the UK :-)

Comment: Also, you should [edit] your question instead of writing comments for any additional details. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing :) so I did edit it, but I didn't comment the edit. I've now edited it again putting in a summary, which hopefully makes it clear what I'm confused about. And I don't think it matters if you are from UK or not! Basically- the form reacts differently when using mechanize via logging in via the browser- why!?